# Compare string literal vs char array

Tags: c

I cannot find a similar answer to this.

```
  char buffer[] = {'a', '0'};
  char p2[] = "a";
  printf("%d", buffer==p2); // prints 0
```

How do I do this comparison? 
Is this a similar question? How do i compare a string literal to a char array.

```
char buffer[] = {'a', '0'};
printf("%d", buffer=="a"); // prints 0
```

The above are just examples, but I really need this:

```
 char buffer[] = {'e','a','b','g','e','l','e','g','o','n','\000','p','k','n','m','l','\000','j', 'i', 'h'};
printf("%d", buffer=="eabgelegon\000pknml\000jih");
```

I cannot use any other functions.

Comment: Use `strcmp` or `strncmp`.

Comment: `buffer` and `p2`, in your `printf()`, are taken as **different** addresses, namely the addresses of each array first element.

Comment: Note that `char buffer[] = {'e','a','b','g','e','l','e','g','o','n','\000','p','k','n','m','l','\000','j', 'i', 'h'};` defines a string with extra data after the `'\000'`. Using string functions on such an array will likely yield unexpected results. Rather than `strcmp()` you will be better off using `memcmp()`.

Comment: you are comparing the address. haccks says the ansqwer.

Comment: With `char buffer[] = {'a', '0'};`, `buffer` is not a C string at it has no terminating `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays (or strings) in many circunstances, are converted to the address of their first element.

In your code, inside the `printf()`, these addresses are being compared.

To compare the stuff pointed to by the addresses you need [`strcmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcmp.html) (for real strings) or [`memcmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memcmp.html) (for binary data)

```
char buffer[] = {'e','a','b','g','e','l','e','g','o','n','\000','p','k','n','m','l','\000','j', 'i', 'h'};

int equal1 = memcmp(buffer, "eabgelegon\000pknml\000jih", 20);
printf("%d", equal1);
int equal2 = memcmp(buffer, "eabgelegon\000XXXXXXXXX", 20);
printf("%d", equal2);

int equal3 = strcmp(buffer, "eabgelegon\000pknml\000jih");
printf("%d", equal3);
int equal4 = strcmp(buffer, "eabgelegon\000XXXXXXXXX");
printf("%d", equal4);
```

Answer (score 1):

None of OP's 3 `buffer` are best described as C strings.  Simply arrays of `char`.

```
char buffer[] = {'a', '0'};  // No terminating \0
char buffer[] = {'a', '0'};  // No terminating \0
// No terminating \0 yet has embedded \0
char buffer[] = {'e','a','b','g','e','l','e','g','o','n','\000','p','k','n','m','l','\000','j', 'i', 'h'};
```

Since OP "cannot use any other functions" ...

Find range of valid indexable memory `buffer` and `p2`.  The valid indexable range of  `buffer` is `0` to `sizeof(buffer) - 1`.

The same for `p2` (the string literal) is complicated.  If `p2` was a typical C string, the range is `0` to `strlen(p2) + 1`.  But a string literal such as `"eabgelegon\000pknml\000jih"` has embedded `'\0'` in it (as well as a terminating `'\0'`), so its range cannot be determined at run time with `strlen()`, but only at compile time with `sizeof()`.

Let's assume the comparison should not include the string literal's terminating `'\0'`.

```
 char buffer[] = 'e','a','b','g','e','l','e','g','o','n','\000','p','k','n','m','l','\000','j', 'i', 'h'};
 char p2[] = "eabgelegon\000pknml\000jih"; // matches
 //char p2[] = "eabgelegon\000pknml\000ji "; // fails
 //char p2[] = "eabgelegon\000pk ml\000jih"; // fails

 size_t buffer_size = sizeof(buffer);
 size_t p2_size = sizeof(p2);
 // p2 should be 1 longer than buffer due to its terminating \0
 if (buffer_size + 1 != p2_size) return NOT_EQUAL; 

 size_t i;
 for (i=0; i<buffer_size; i++) {
   if (buffer[i] != p2[i]) return NOT_EQUAL;
 }
 return EQUAL;
```

Note: `sizeof()` is not a function in C, but an operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't recognize it:

```
char buffer[] = {'a', '\0'};
char p2[] = "a";
```

`buffer` and `p2` are **exactly** the same. With `buffer` you declare a character array and assign the first character as `'a'` and then an explicit **null-terminating character** `'\0'` giving you a string `"a"`. With `p2` you assign the string literal `"a"` and the null-terminating character is **automatically** appended to the end. Either way -- you get the same thing, `buffer` and `p2` hold the string `"a"`.

Comment: OP has `char buffer[] = {'a', '0'};` and this answer has `char buffer[] = {'a', '\0'};`.  OP's `buffer`  is not a C string.  this answer's `buffer` is a string.

Comment: Good catch. I'll amend. (the question has been greatly extended since the answer was posted) Not only extended -- **it has been changed** The specification of the problem above was a **copy** or the original question. Obviously, if you change the question, then the answer to the original question, will no longer apply as written.

Comment: @chux -- just so we are clear. The question as originally posted was `char buffer[] = {'a', '\0'};` The question was changed after this answer was posted (and I suspect will be changed again as `{'a', '0'}` makes little sense and strcmp would puke at a non-null-terminated string) (strcmp has also been removed apparently)