# Compare char array element to string literal

Tags: c, arrays, string

I've been trying get part of a string from a char array, and for the life of me, I cannot get any of the examples I've found on StackOverflow to work:
[Compare string literal vs char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25528380/compare-string-literal-vs-char-array)
I've looked all over the internet for a solution, I've tried mixing pointers, strcmp, strncmp, everything I can think of.

I cannot see how to get this to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
 const char S[] = "0.9";
 if (S[1] == ".") {
    puts("got it");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I realize posting this may ruin my reputation... but I could not find the solution.... similar articles didn't work.

thanks in advance for your help :/

*EDIT*: I was not aware of the correct search terms to use; that's why I didn't find the specified original.

Comment: You are comparing a `char` value to a `char` pointer. Change `"."` to `'.'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"."` is a string literal. What you want should be a character constant `'.'`.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
 const char S[] = "0.9";
 if (S[1] == '.') {
    puts("got it");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Alternative (but looks worse) way: access an element of the string literal

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
 const char S[] = "0.9";
 if (S[1] == "."[0]) {
    puts("got it");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you MikeCAT, I learned something new about C today I had never heard this before, an excellent explanation is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c

Comment: Is it valid to write *"."  ??